# how to move identical elements in numpy array into subarrays

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

How do I efficiently move identical elements from a sorted numpy array into subarrays?

from here:

```
import numpy as np     
a=np.array([0,0,1,1,1,3,5,5,5])
```

to here:

```
a2=array([[0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [3], [5, 5, 5]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Are the elements always sorted in the input array?

Comment: yes, i've now updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to get the places of shifts, where the numbers change and use those indices to split the input array into subarrays. For finding those indices, you can use [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) on a differentiated array and then use [`np.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) for splitting, like so -

```
np.split(a,np.nonzero(np.diff(a))[0]+1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: a
Out[42]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6])

In [43]: np.split(a,np.nonzero(np.diff(a))[0]+1)
Out[43]: 
[array([2, 2, 2, 2]),
 array([3, 3, 3, 3]),
 array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]),
 array([5, 5]),
 array([6, 6, 6])]
```

Answer (score 2):

One method to do this would be using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) . Example -

```
result = np.array([list(g) for _,g in groupby(a)])
```

This would work for normal sorted lists as well, not just numpy arrays.

Demo -

```
In [24]: import numpy as np

In [25]: a=np.array([0,0,1,1,1,3,5,5,5])

In [26]: from itertools import groupby

In [27]: result = np.array([list(g) for _,g in groupby(a)])

In [28]: result
Out[28]: array([[0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [3], [5, 5, 5]], dtype=object)
```

---

Timing comparison with the other approach -

```
In [29]: %timeit np.array([list(g) for _,g in groupby(a)])
The slowest run took 6.10 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.86 µs per loop

In [30]: %timeit np.split(a,np.where(np.diff(a)>0)[0]+1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.2 µs per loop

In [31]: %timeit np.array([list(g) for _,g in groupby(a)])
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.5 µs per loop

In [33]: %timeit np.split(a,np.nonzero(np.diff(a))[0]+1)
The slowest run took 4.32 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.2 µs per loop
```